# How do I add production settings to my luanchSettings.json file for production?

Tags: .net-core

I want to setup my dotnet core mvc application to run on ubuntu.

How do set my launch settings.json file for production environment?

I have this currently, but not sure how to change the applicationUrl for production and keep what I have for development.  Very confused...

```
{
  "iisSettings": {
    "windowsAuthentication": false, 
    "anonymousAuthentication": true, 
    "iisExpress": {
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:17009",
      "sslPort": 44319
    }
  },
  "profiles": {
    "IIS Express": {
      "commandName": "IISExpress",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    },
    "MyApp.Brain": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "applicationUrl": "https://localhost:5001;http://localhost:5000",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`launchSettings.json` is only meant for development purposes - to tell `dotnet run` or Visual Studio / IDEs what to set up.

For production, you can for example create an `appsettings.Production.json`  containing something like

```
{
  "Kestrel": {
    "Endpoints": {
      "Http": {
        "Url": "http://*:1234"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Or use other ways of configuring the endpoint, like the `ASPNETCORE_URLS` environment variable or using a command line parameter when staring up the app (`dotnet yourapp.dll --urls "http://*:1234"`).

See [Kestrel Options documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/servers/kestrel?view=aspnetcore-3.1#kestrel-options) for other configuration options for the Kestrel server (default on linux) or [Host and Deploy ASP.NET Core documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/?view=aspnetcore-3.1) for different hosting options on linux.

Comment: Then why does the documentation here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/linux-apache?view=aspnetcore-6.0#publish-and-copy-over-the-app ask us to modify the `launchSettings.json`?